# GET request to JSON file after PHP file is finished running

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am calling a php file from an angular front end.

The php file checks for tweets every ten minutes, and after this time updates a json file which is then called from angular. I have an angular factory with 2 methods. The first method, called `updateTwitter()` makes a `GET` request to the php file which then makes a GET request to Twitter and returns tweets. These are then written to a JSON file. The second method `fetchTwitter()` makes a GET request to this JSON file and displays the data on the front end.

My question is how should I call these methods in my controller. I feel I should use a promise, and say something like, until the first method (updateTwitter()`) has finished don't run`fecthTwitter()`. Is this the correct approach, and if so , how should I write this?

My code looks like this.

**php**

```
<?php
require_once('twitter_proxy.php');
// Twitter OAuth Config options
$oauth_access_token = '*****';
$oauth_access_token_secret = '*****';
$consumer_key = '*****';
$consumer_secret = '*****';
$user_id = '*****';
$screen_name = 'StackOverflow';
$count = 5;
$twitter_url = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';
$twitter_url .= '?user_id=' . $user_id;
$twitter_url .= '&screen_name=' . $screen_name;
$twitter_url .= '&count=' . $count;
// Create a Twitter Proxy object from our twitter_proxy.php class
$twitter_proxy = new TwitterProxy(
    $oauth_access_token,            // 'Access token' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $oauth_access_token_secret,     // 'Access token secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_key,                  // 'API key' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_secret,               // 'API secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $user_id,                       // User id (http://gettwitterid.com/)
    $screen_name,                   // Twitter handle
    $count                          // The number of tweets to pull out
);

function checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url) {
    $tweets = $twitter_proxy->get($twitter_url);
    $data = array ('twitter_result' => $tweets, 'timestamp' => time());
    file_put_contents('twitter_result.json', json_encode($data));
}

//check if the file exists
if(!file_exists('twitter_result.json')) {
    //Invoke the get method to retrieve results via a cURL request
    //and create a file with timestamp containing tweets
    checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);

}else {
    //if file exists check it has not been updated in 10 minutes
    //if not update the tweets and timestamp
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('twitter_result.json'));
    if ($data->{"timestamp"} > (time() - 10 * 60)) {
        checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);
    }
}
```

Angular code

**factory.js**

```
//factory used to make GET request to Instagram
app.factory('socialMedia', ['$http', function($http){
return {

    updateTwitter: function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'get_tweets.php',
            method: 'GET'
        })
    },
    fetchTwitter: function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'twitter_result.json',
            method: 'GET'
        })
    }
}
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller("testCtrl", ["$routeParams", "socialMedia", function ($routeParams, socialMedia) {

    testCtrl = this;
    this.twitterPosts = [];

    socialMedia.updateTwitter();

    socialMedia.fetchTwitter().success(function(data){
        socialMedia.updateTwitter();
        var result = JSON.parse(data.twitter_result);
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            testCtrl.twitterPosts.push(result[i]);
        }      
    })
    .error(function () {
        testCtrl.loading = false;
        testCtrl.error = true;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$http.get` method returns the promise you can easily chain your calls like this:

```
socialMedia.updateTwitter()
.then(function() {
    socialMedia.fetchTwitter()
    .then(function(data){
        ...
    })
});
```

Also note, according to the [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead

Hence, your controller should look the following way:

```
app.controller("testCtrl", ["$routeParams", "socialMedia", function ($routeParams, socialMedia) {
    testCtrl = this;
    this.twitterPosts = [];

    socialMedia.updateTwitter()
    .then(function(){
        socialMedia.fetchTwitter()
        .then(function(response){
            var data = response.data;
            var result = JSON.parse(data.twitter_result);
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                testCtrl.twitterPosts.push(result[i]);
            }      
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            testCtrl.loading = false;
            testCtrl.error = true;
        });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: could you update the answer showing how I should replace `success` and `error`?

Comment: @phantom, here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that'd be a good approach. Execute the second request as a callback for the first one or chain them using the promise's `.then()` method.
But why aren't you just passing the data in the first request's response instead of doing another second request?

Comment: Try not to answer a question with a question, a comment would be more appropriate.